# Makefile -- compile only modified C++ files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This is my current makefile

```
CFLAGS = -Iheaders/
CC = g++

PROGRAM_NAME = sportsmanager
rwildcard    = $(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))
SOURCES      = $(call rwildcard,sources/,*.cpp)
OFILES       = $(call rwildcard,obj-tmp/,*.o)
OBJDIR       = obj-tmp/

compileAndRun: 
    make -s compile && make -s $(PROGRAM_NAME)
    ./$(PROGRAM_NAME)

compile: $(SOURCES)
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SOURCES) && mv *.o $(OBJDIR)

$(PROGRAM_NAME): $(OFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OFILES) -o $(PROGRAM_NAME)
```

Whenever I run `$ make`, target `compile` is triggered which compiles all `.cpp` files in directory `sources/` to `.o` files which are then moved to `obj-tmp/`. Then the target `$(PROGRAM_NAME)` is triggered, which links all the `.o` files and outputs the executable file.

The problem is that **all** files are compiled each time I run `make`. What ideally should happen if I run 'make' twice in succession is that make should know that the program is up to date the second time. If I modify only one file, only that file should be compiled.

Heads up: I know that there exists similar questions regarding this, but I've yet to see a solution which works in conjunction with the above makefile.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your command explicitly tells it to compile every file--there's no way that will ever work. You need to tell make *how* to compile a single file (with a % rule), set the dependencies, and it will magically do the right thing.

Comment: Don't copy .o files - have them created in the directory you want to place them in. And this is a pretty crappy makefile.

Comment: Don't spam tags. And read the documentation of `make`. It is very comprehensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of make is to compile only those files which have been modified since the last build. The problem in your makefile is that your `compile` recipe has the `$(SOURCES)` variable as a dependency. As in, *all* the source files.

I would use `vpath` to organize the project folder like so:

```
vpath %.cpp src
vpath %.h include
```

This will tell `make` to look for c++ files in `./src` and header files in `./include`. Then, you can simplify your recipe for *individual* files like this:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Having done this, you can now define an `$(OBJECTS)` variable with a wildcard that matches `.o` files and continue from there. As an aside, moving your object files into a separate folder is considered bad practice and I agree; it really adds nothing substantial of value but complicates recipes.

Remember that object files represent a dependency for the `$(PROGRAM)` recipe. So naturally, make looks for the necessary object files to see if they need to be rebuilt. If they've been moved, one of two things happens. Either make will determine that they don't exist and will rebuild *all* the object files again from scratch, thereby invalidating the very reason we use make in the first place, or you'll have to define a folder where the object files will live, and every time you handle wildcards, searches, etc., literally anything that has to do with the object files, you'll have to take this added complexity into account.

I agree that having a ton of object files in the project folder can be a little annoying, but it definitely beats waiting forever for the project to compile. Just remember to add `*.o` to your `.gitignore` or whatever source control platform you use and they'll be nothing more than an eyesore, while make will be that much easier to use.

---

To answer your question on handling subdirectories in the source folder, the answer is a little more complicated.

Rather than using the specific `vpath <pattern> <folder>` directive as above, you could just outright use the `VPATH` variable like this:

```
VPATH = include src src/sub
```

This would handle the job, but the first method is usually preferred because when using `VPATH`, make searches *every directory every time* when looking for a file, rather than being location-constrained by file extension.

It is possible to use make to conveniently manage large projects though, and it involves calling `make` itself recursively, writing makefiles for each module in the build process. This process is obviously much more complicated, and I would strongly recommend considering whether the project genuinely necessitates this, as any potential gains in build-process modularization may not be recuperated due to the complexity involved in implementation.

I'd like to point you to [this](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/#rule3) and [this](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/#rule3), both of which are phenomenal resources on makefiles.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Why is it considered a bad practise to move .o files? When you work in a large directory it's pretty jarring to have the root of your file-tree ridden with files you never touch.

Comment: I added in an explanation, let me know if it helps

Comment: I see, that helped. A last question, can you apply 'vpath' recursively? e.g. taking into account src/sub/file.cpp?

Comment: Thank you for all the great answers and the resources!

Comment: I don't think it was stupid question. You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the dependency of `compile` to be the object files.
2. Add a pattern rule for the object files.

---

```
compile: $(OFILES)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: sources/%.cpp
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a lot of good input in this thread! Here's a follow up. I've now updated the script to the following:

```
CC           = g++
CFLAGS       = -Iheaders/
PROGRAM_NAME = sportsmanager
OFILES       = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard sources/*.cpp))

vpath %.cpp sources

compileAndRun:
    @make -s $(PROGRAM_NAME)
    @./$(PROGRAM_NAME)

$(PROGRAM_NAME): $(OFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROGRAM_NAME) $(OFILES)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM_NAME) $(OFILES)
```

Any suggestions for further improvements are very welcome!